# Restructuring folder-based to Lightroom keywords

Tags: lightroom

I recently resurrected an old computer which held my photos from 2001-2015, and am looking at how to best import them into my Lightroom catalog. The photos are right now in folders `<year>/<dotted date or date-range>, <occasion>`, e.g. `2008/2008.07.01-10, Mountain hike` or `2010/2010.06.29-07.01, Visiting mom`.

With my newer pictures, I've let Lightroom just import them to date-of-capture and used keywords to manage the "occasion" bit (and people in images etc).

I'd like to import the old images into the same date-based structure, and with keywords added for the occasion taken from the folder name. Is there a way to do this without a lot of manual work? Any automation tooling that can help?